# Django: manipulate model in view

Tags: django

I want to access, update or create a new entry in a database through a django model, from within a viewset.

```
class UploadView(View):

    def post(self, request):
        file = request.FILES['file']
        data = request.POST['myObj']
        profile_id = request.POST['profile_id']
        profile = ProfileModel.objects.all().filter(pk=profile_id)
        print (profile.id)
        print(profile.details)
        return HttpResponse('got post')
```

and model

```
class ProfileModel(models.Model):
    '''
    '''
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    details = models.CharField(max_length=256)     
    file = models.BinaryField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Profile'
```

When it reaches the print statement it throws an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`profile` is a queryset not an individual profile, so it shouldn't have an `id` field

If you're supposed to have an individual profile you could use the [`get`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) method

`profile = ProfileModel.objects.get(pk=profile_id)`

`get` can throw a `DoesNotExist` if there is no matchign ProfileModel

Comment: and how could I create a new entry if does not exist

Comment: `get_or_create` django provides lots of methods built in its very helpful to look at model documentation, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create, or you could attempt to `get` and on `DoesNotExist` create it.  You could also use djangso built in CBV's to comeup with a workflow to perform CRUD operations on your objects

Comment: Ok, thanks for this, do you have any idea on this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705246/django-store-uploaded-file-to-mysql-database